# Make all objects in elastic search nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to make all nested objects in elastic search automatically map to the type nested by default. Instead of object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do it by using the following [dynamic template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html) when creating your index:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "dynamic_templates": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "match_mapping_type": "object",
            "mapping": {
              "type": "nested"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add a practical example of this?