# Update NonNested Property to Nested Type in ElasticSearch Document

Tags: elasticsearch

We are creating a dynamic object in an elasticsearch index. While creation we don't have a mapping for this object so object created with `nonnested` type as mentioned below.

```
"categoriesScore": {
    "properties": {
          "score": {
             "type": "float"
           },
          "categoryName": {
             "type": "text",
             "fields": {
                 "keyword": {
                      "ignore_above": 256,
                      "type": "keyword"
                  }
              }
           },
           "categoryId": {
                  "type": "long"
           }
   }
},
```

So we need to update property type to `nested` for some `nonnested` object.

we have tried below code

```
await _client.MapAsync<DocumentEntity> (c => c.Index(_index).Type(_type)).ConfigureAwait (false);
```

We need NEST query so we can update `nonnested` type to `nested` type document

Comment: this answer should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40198487/make-all-objects-in-elastic-search-nested-objects/40199280#40199280 (hint: you cannot change to nested once the index is created)

Comment: This is not working for me :( 
I have created an index with nonnested and then I am trying to make it nested.

Comment: Too late, once a mapping is created you cannot change it anymore. You need to create another index with the correct mapping and reindex your data